# How can I install qedit.dll to Windows Server 2008 R2 Sp1

Tags: windows-server-2008, dll

I need to install `qedit.dll` to windows server 2008 R2 SP1

Can you help me with this ?

I tried 2 dll file. One from my local computer which is windows 7 sp1 and another one I downloaded from internet. Both giving error when I try to register. Here the error screenshot

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you're running x64 Windows. If that dll is 32-bit, then you need to drop it in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and use `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe` to register it.